# How to make async query in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, query

Is any way to make asynchronius query to wordpress, where i can use wordpress functions?
For example:
 
I make in my plugin file `add_post.php` which contains:

```
if($_POST['new_post'] == true) 
    wp_insert_post( $_POST['post_data'] );
```

and using ajax I send query to execute above code.
Where `wp_insert_post()` is wordpress function defined in `wp-includes/post.php`.

Comment: Ajax is by definition asynchronous (that's what the first A stands for). So if your question is whether it's possible: yes, it is. If you have a specific problem implementing it, you might want to clarify where you are struggling.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by an async query, do you mean a non-blocking query that goes and does its stuff in the background so your PHP can continue to the next thing?

Comment: Also, you should be using REST endpoints or WP Admin AJAX for JS requests, you should never make a call directly to a PHP file inside your theme, it's a huuge security problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any way to make asynchronius query to wordpress, where i can use wordpress functions?

Yes, but it's:

- super fragile and easy to break
- a big security problem

I **strongly** advise against it, and would consider the fix needed to make it work irresponsible to share.

**Instead, save yourself a world of pain and use a REST API endpoint**, or the official AJAX API, e.g.

```
// add the endpoint
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'salk/v1', '/test/', array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'salk_rest_test'
        ) );
} );

function salk_rest_test( $request ) {
    // do things here
    // access POST things like this $request['post_data']
    // anything you return gets json encoded and sent back to the browser
}
```

Placed in a plugin or a themes functions file, then use `jQuery.post` with the URL `example.com/wp-json/salk/v1/test/`

Better yet, WordPress already provides a JS endpoint at `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` that you can use to create posts from the frontend if you're logged in